# 401 with Google Proximity API

Tags: api, authentication, proximity, beacon

after following the step-by-step instructions (https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides) I can successfully enable the Google Proximity Beacon API and create both API key and OAuth 2.0 client IDs for the App I created in the Google Developers Console.
Everything appears to be set up fine: the Google Proximity Beacon API shows to be active and "Credentials" tabs shows both API Key and OAuth 2.0 client ID.

The problem occurs when I try calling   my Beacon: the Response gives me a "401" error:

```
    ...
     "code": 401,
     "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
     "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    ...
```

The strange thing is that if I try the oauthplayground, again following google's proximity docs, I get a 403 error:

```
    {
      "error": {
      "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
      "message": "Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the 'proximitybeacon' API for your project.", 
      "code": 403, 
      "details": [
      ...
```

I'm kind of lost here...anyone?
Thank you in advance.

Flik